# Appending unit labels to AxesLabel or FrameLabel

Tags: plotting, labeling

I want to append a label showing the units for the quantity $|m_{ee}|$ plotted on the y-axis; i.e I want the `FrameLabel` to read $|m_{ee}|(eV)$ on y-axis.

Please help me. Here is the code that I am using:

```
mee[β_, α_, c12_, c13_, s12_, s13_,m1_, m2_, m3_] := √(m1 c12^2 c13^2 + 
      m2 s12^2 s13^2 Cos[2 α Degree] + 
      m3 s12^2 c13^2 Cos[2 β Degree])^2 + (m2 s12^2 c13^2 Sin[
       2 α Degree] + m3 s13^2 Sin[2 β Degree])^2;
Tab23 = Table[{β, 
    mee[β, Random[Real, {-25, 25}], 
     Random[Real, {0.851, 0.8062}], Random[Real, {0.9897, 0.9877}], 
     Random[Real, {0.5241, 0.5915}], Random[Real, {0.1429, 0.1562}], 
     Random[Real, {0, 0.001}], Random[Real, {0.00832, 0.00892}], 
     Random[Real, {0.0486, 0.0512}]]}, {β, -45, 45, 1 Degree}];
P23 = ListPlot[Tab23, PlotRange -> {0, 0.1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {β, Abs[Subscript[m, ee]]}, 
  FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Bold, 13], Frame -> True]
```

Comment: You mean like this?  Change to `FrameLabel -> {\[Beta], Row[{Abs[Subscript[m, ee]], (eV)}]},` and see if it does what you want. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ac8kD.png)  but I would use MaTeX myself for these types of Labels as Latex looks better.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. Really grateful for your reply.

Comment: If I want to put eV within square bracket what should I do?

Comment: You could try `FrameLabel -> {\[Beta], Row[{Abs[Subscript[m, ee]], "[", eV, "]"}]},`  and see. another option is `FrameLabel -> {\[Beta], 
  Row[{Abs[     Subscript[m, ee]], \[LeftAngleBracket]eV\[RightAngleBracket]}]},`  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePEy.png)